# how to get a word if given x and y word?

Tags: bash, find

```
Ch  SSID                             BSSID               Security               Signal(%)W-Mode       ExtCH  NT
52  xxxxxx-F3F6BD                    12:13:31:xx:xx:xx   WPA2PSK/AES            100      11a/n/ac     ABOVE  In
112 ROGER                            92:02:db:xx:xx:xx   WPAPSKWPA2PSK/TKIPAES  73       11a/n/ac     BELOW  In
112 router                           11:22:33:xx:xx:xx   WPA2PSK/AES            73       11a/n/ac     BELOW  In
36  TIM-9xxxxx                       b4:a5:ef:xx:xx:xx   WPA2PSK/AES            55       11a/n/ac     ABOVE  In
36  TIM-27xxxxxx                     12:13:31:xx:xx:xx   WPA2PSK/AES            44       11a/n/ac     ABOVE  In
```

I want to get the specific value/word if given an X word and Y word. The Y word is always from the first line:Ch SSID BSSID  Security....
For example, if the X word is ROUGER and Y word is BSSID, i will get 92:02:db:xx:xx:xx .
If the X word is router and Y word is Ch, i will get 112

Comment: I suggest to take a look at `awk`. See: https://www.google.com/search?q=awk+select+field+by+column+name

Answer (score 0):

Try this `awk` program:

```
NR == 1 {
    # Memorization of first line column names with position
    i = 1
    while (i <= NF) {
        hash_cols[$i] = i
        i++
    }
    next
}
NR > 1 && $0 ~ S_PATTERN && hash_cols[S_COL] > 0 {
    print $hash_cols[S_COL]
}
```

Run on commande line like this:

```sh
$ cat route.txt | awk -f route.awk -v S_PATTERN="ROGER" -v S_COL="BSSID"
92:02:db:xx:xx:xx
```

Here the `cat route.txt` could be replaced by any commands that you want.

Also, you could place `awk` command in a shell script:

```sh
#! /bin/bash

cat                   \
| awk                 \
    -v S_PATTERN="$1" \
    -v S_COL="$2"     \
    '
    NR == 1 {
        i = 1
        while (i <= NF) {
            hash_cols[$i] = i
            i++
        }
        next
    }
    NR > 1 && $0 ~ S_PATTERN && hash_cols[S_COL] > 0 {
        print $hash_cols[S_COL]
    }
    '
```

And launch it:

```sh
$ cat route.txt | ./route.sh "ROGER" "BSSID"
92:02:db:xx:xx:xx
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this awk.

```
awk -v row="ROGER" -v column="BSSID" ' match($0,column);match($0,row) ' jing.txt | \
awk -v column="BSSID" ' {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i==column) break; getline; print $i } '

92:02:db:xx:xx:xx
```

Or even shorter

```
$ awk -v row="ROGER" ' NR==1;match($0,row) ' jing.txt |\
  awk -v column="BSSID" ' {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i==column) break; getline; print $i } '
92:02:db:xx:xx:xx
```